# Редактирование модели. Ошибка. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[justfortest.Models.Book]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь создать редактирование модели. Выскакивает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Index.cshtml :**

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model justfortest.Models.Book

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Название книги")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Author, "Автор")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Author)

        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, "Цена")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
BookContext db = new BookContext();
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View(db.Books);
}

[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Index(Book book)
{
    db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}



protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    db.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Модели есть. Таблицы БД заполнены данными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты передаешь в представление модель с типом `DbSet<Book>`

```
return View(db.Books);
```

но ожидаешь в разметке `justfortest.Models.Book` как и ожидаешь в методе `public ActionResult Index(Book book)`. И справедливо получаешь исключение, в процессе обработки разметки, из-за рассогласованных типов моделей.

Comment: Я изменил в BookContext на  public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; } и при передачи поменял Books на Book. Таблица в бд у меня тоже Book. Правильно ли я сделал ?

Comment: Но ошибка все равно

Comment: Нет. DbSet<Book> — это некоторая абстрактная коллекция сущностей Book из базы данных. А вы в вашей разметке ожидаете получить **один** экземпляр Book. Вам нужно взять из DbSet<T> один элемент и передать его во вью. Например, так: db.Books.First()